# AJAX: Request has string appened, messing up call

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery

I have a problem, i believe it is related to my ajax, hence the title.
I have a script:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){
        $file="imgs/uploads/slideshow/".$row['image_location'];

        if(file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$file)){
            $location = $file;//"imgs/uploads/thumbs/".$row['image_location'];
        } else if(!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$file)){
            $location = "imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/".$row['image_location']."&preset=slideshow";
        }
        $lightboxUrl = "imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/".$row['image_location']."&preset=lightbox2";
        $date = $index->formatDate($row['image_upload']);
        $name = $row['image_name'];
        print<<<HERE
            <div>
                <a href='$lightboxUrl' class='lightbox'>
                    <img title='$date' src='$location'/>
                </a>
            </div>";
HERE;
}
```

Printing inside an ajax loaded tab(jquery ui). And it works properly for all but the very first image. The first image called has a request url like so:
`http://localhost/site/imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371269676r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.JPG&preset=slideshow?1337224225894`
See that `?1337224225894` on the end?
That is what is messing it up.
That `?` on in the bit added to the url invalidates the request url and the parameters are not passed to the script, thus i get the full image not the re-sized one.

All the other urls are correct. I can even echo that url in the script and it is correct but when it is called it gets messed up.
I have a vague idea this is caused by the no cache parameters used in my tabs instance but it does not make sense as it used to work.
Any idea?

EDIT: Strangely the same script seems to work perfectly when called by a normal ajax request vs the tabs deal, at least that is the only dif between the scripts i can see.

EDIT2:
requested tabs initialize script:

```
 $(function(){
        $('#slides').slides({
            preload: true,
            generateNextPrev: false,
            preloadImage: 'imgs/loading.gif',
            //bigTarget: true,
            play: 5000,
            slideSpeed: 3000,
            generatePagination: false


        });
    });
```

Here is the markup as given by view source:

```
<div id="content">

        <div class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="tabs">
            <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
                <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#ui-tabs-1" id="public">Public View</a></li>
                <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#settings">Settings</a></li>
                <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" id="editLink"><a href="#ui-tabs-2" id="edit">Edit Blog</a></li>
                <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#profile" "="">Profile</a></li>
            </ul><div class="ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom" id="ui-tabs-1">                      
            <div id="slides">
                    <div style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; display: block;" class="slides_container">                <div style="position: relative; width: 1800px; height: 600px; left: -600px;" class="slides_control"><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 600px; z-index: 5; display: block;">
             imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371269676r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.JPG&amp;preset=slideshow
                <a href="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371269676r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.JPG&amp;preset=lightbox2" class="lightbox">
                    <img title="Yesterday @ 20:09" src="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371269676r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.JPG&amp;preset=slideshow?1337226056936">
                </a>
            </div><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 600px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
             imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371236426r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.jpg&amp;preset=slideshow
                <a href="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371236426r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.jpg&amp;preset=lightbox2" class="lightbox">
                    <img title="Yesterday @ 19:14" src="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371236426r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.jpg&amp;preset=slideshow">
                </a>
            </div><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 600px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
             imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371234386r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.jpg&amp;preset=slideshow
                <a href="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371234386r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.jpg&amp;preset=lightbox2" class="lightbox">
                    <img title="Yesterday @ 19:10" src="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371234386r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.jpg&amp;preset=slideshow">
                </a>
            </div><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 600px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
             imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371233356r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.jpg&amp;preset=slideshow
                <a href="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371233356r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.jpg&amp;preset=lightbox2" class="lightbox">
                    <img title="Yesterday @ 19:08" src="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371233356r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.jpg&amp;preset=slideshow">
                </a>
            </div><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 600px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
             imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371232486r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.jpg&amp;preset=slideshow
                <a href="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371232486r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.jpg&amp;preset=lightbox2" class="lightbox">
                    <img title="Yesterday @ 19:07" src="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371232486r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.jpg&amp;preset=slideshow">
                </a>
            </div><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 600px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
             imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371230636r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.JPG&amp;preset=slideshow
                <a href="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371230636r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.JPG&amp;preset=lightbox2" class="lightbox">
                    <img title="Yesterday @ 19:04" src="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371230636r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.JPG&amp;preset=slideshow">
                </a>
            </div><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 600px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
             imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371228826r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.JPG&amp;preset=slideshow
                <a href="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371228826r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.JPG&amp;preset=lightbox2" class="lightbox">
                    <img title="Yesterday @ 19:01" src="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/113371228826r84gq9re1vppfram0a7ajgo15.JPG&amp;preset=slideshow">
                </a>
            </div><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 600px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
             imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/11337107020jcemicq53t6g1h7m7kbfre77i1.JPG&amp;preset=slideshow
                <a href="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/11337107020jcemicq53t6g1h7m7kbfre77i1.JPG&amp;preset=lightbox2" class="lightbox">
                    <img title="Yesterday @ 14:37" src="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/11337107020jcemicq53t6g1h7m7kbfre77i1.JPG&amp;preset=slideshow">
                </a>
            </div><div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 600px; z-index: 0; display: none;">
             imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/11337106997jcemicq53t6g1h7m7kbfre77i1.jpg&amp;preset=slideshow
                <a href="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/11337106997jcemicq53t6g1h7m7kbfre77i1.jpg&amp;preset=lightbox2" class="lightbox">
                    <img title="Yesterday @ 14:36" src="imgs/resize.php?file=uploads/11337106997jcemicq53t6g1h7m7kbfre77i1.jpg&amp;preset=slideshow">
                </a>
            </div></div>";                                      </div> <!-- End # slide_container -->

                    <a href="#" class="prev"><img src="imgs/arrow-prev.png" alt="Arrow Prev" height="43" width="24"></a>
                    <a href="#" class="next"><img src="imgs/arrow-next.png" alt="Arrow Next" height="43" width="24"></a>
            </div> <!-- End # slides --></div>
```

EDIT3:
New strange discovery. Using firebug i discovered the following. The header is sent correctly the correct data is received, and according to firebug the source code is correct, but if i got to web dev addon generated source it shows that extra string. So it is somewhere between the receiving of the data and the printing of it. I think....

This happens no matter what the first image is it is in no way connected to the image or file location I have tested with different locations and files.

Comment: could you explain how it is messing up?

Comment: That `?` on in the bit added to the url invalidates the request url and the parameters are not passed to the script, thus i get the full image not the re-sized one.

Comment: Did you try urlencode for the '?'

Comment: What is that? Im not sure what you mean.

Comment: Php has a urlencode function. It will encode special characters to urlencoded codes like space to %20. This helps when you have special character in url parameter. http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Ah... But i don't want that char in there, it is not a valid parameter for my re-size script so i want to figure out why it is there and how to remove it. Edit and as i said, the php script is passing the correct url but it is somehow being added to. I can print the url in the script and it is correct the string is added after sending but before arrival at destination so to speak.

Comment: Could you post how you initialize your tabs? Also some markup would be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

The "=""  in the "profile" li will mess thing up a bit! What happens if you correct that?

The a link is messed up because of it, and hence you're in trouble for that entire a element!

---

EDit: Is the code above what you get from "view source" or from Firebug? The ? is clearly shown in the image URL src, and that is what is passed to the light box (not the a href)

So if "view source"then check what creates the source, as that is adding the ? bit. If from Firebug, we'll need more code to find where the src could be modified by Javascript.

Comment: That does not make any difference. Thanks for spotting it though, it was showing up on the page and i had not figured out where it was.